# Flat icon img not displaying only in some pages even with the same template and extends

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this website http://www.portalbrasilonline.com.br/ that works fine, but only now I realize that some pages are not "rendering" in 100%, for example with you click in top menu "Por Estados" and after that chose a state (brazilian states) you will see that the footer is not showing the images anymore.

The strange thing is that Im using the SAME template in ALL PAGES, but some of them show the image and anothers do not show.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection
```

Since it was supposed to render the same content I REALLY do not know what should I do. Sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image path is `relative` as opposed to `absolute.`

Prepend the path with a `/` to stop this.

Comment: Thank you! It really works! But I still can not understand why sometimes the icon appears and sometimes it does not appears since it is the same file. Weird thing.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel comes with many helper functions available [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers). The one you'd benefit from using would be `asset()` which can be used like: `{{ asset('img/image.png') }}` within your blade template which would generate a URL for your asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS).

Comment: The other question saved me but Im using this {{asset()}} lately and it really can help! Thank you